# wp_logout() not working after form submission

Tags: page-template, wp-redirect, logout

I am pretty new to Wordpress, so please forgive me if this sounds like a silly question.

I have a Wordpress Page which is using the default `page.php` template in my theme.  I modified the `page.php` file to include an if-statement which calls code using `get_template_part();` depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

If the user is logged in, I want the person to fill out the form, which has an `action` that is pointing to a Thank You page that I created.  That page saves the contents of the form to the database and then redirects the user to a third party site.  I need to log the user out of the Wordpress site before redirecting them, but for some reason the user stays logged in even after I use `wp_logout();` and redirect using `wp_redirect();`

Here is example of the code I just described:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  get_template_part( 'page-templates/user-logged-in-page', 'user-is-logged-in' );
} else {
  get_template_part( 'page-templates/user-should-login-page', 'user-needs-to-login' );
}
```

Here is the code for the logic on the Thank You page that redirects to the third party site:

```
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && !empty($_POST["user_entry"]) ) {

  $user_entry = strip_tags($_POST["user_entry"], "");
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  update_user_meta( $user_id , 'user_entry' , $user_entry );

  wp_logout();  // This line is not working!

  wp_redirect( 'https://www.mythirdpartysite.com/' );
  exit();

}
```

However, after the redirect happens, when I visit the Wordpress site again, I am still logged in!

Does anyone know why the `wp_logout()` function is not working for me?

**EDIT:**

Additionally, I am not sure if this has anything to do with the fact that the `wp_logout` function is not working as expected, but, the following is also a part of my code:

```
function app_output_buffer() {
  ob_start();
}
add_action('init', 'app_output_buffer');
```

Comment: Where are these code snippets located? And at what point do they run? For these things the timing is important, you can't redirect and logout halfway down a page if you've already sent content for example

Comment: This is all happening within a plugin.  The code for the form itself is in the theme.  I am having a hard time understanding how to do the redirect anywhere else.

Comment: `wp_logout()` and `wp_redirect()` with the `ob_start()` stuff, all worked well for me. So if you could show the whole code with the `wp_logout()` call there (including where it's being called - e.g. during the `init`, `template_redirect`, etc. "action"), maybe we could help you further. But I'm guessing that in your case, the *cookies* were failed to be set - maybe there has been an output sent to the browser.

Comment: what is this whole "output already sent to browser" business.  This is the error I am seeing onscreen (repeating about 20 times on the screen).

Comment: Well, it's exactly as it says.. you probably call the `wp_logout()` after there has been some output/content sent to the browser or printed on screen, even just a space. See the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for `header()` which `wp_redirect()` uses, and [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) which `wp_logout()` uses. Both the manual warn you about making sure no output has been sent to the browser prior to calling `header()` or `setcookie()`.

Comment: So if you got "thanks for your submission" on the screen, and *then* or after that call `wp_logout()`, that won't work because of the "thanks for ..." text (the output) has already been sent to you or the browser.